# Fourier Transform of $1/(\pi\cdot t)$ by Duality

Tags: proof-verification, fourier-analysis

I'm asked to prove using "duality property" the Fourier transform of 
$$\frac{1}{\pi t} = -j sgn(f)$$

I have the proof steps but I'm quit not understanding it:

1. multiply by $j = \frac{j}{j(\pi t)}$
2. $j2\pi x(-w)$
3. $2j\pi(-0.5+U(-w))$

multiplying by $2$ and factoring $- sgn$ gives:

$$-j( 1-2U(-w))= -j*sgn (f)$$

*correction: ignore the above steps as they are confusing, consider this answer:

prove $$\frac{1}{πt} ↔ -j sgn(f)$$

Using the duality theorem which state:

If $x(t) ↔ X(f)$

then  $X(t) ↔ x(-f)$

Let $x(t) = \frac{1}{πt}$ and $X(t) = -j sgn(f)$

Then by duality theorem:

$-j sgn(t) ↔ - \frac{1}{πf}$

Calculating Fourier Transform of $–jsgn(t)$:

$\mathcal{F}[-j sgn(t) ]= -j \mathcal{F}[sgn(t)]$

Fourier transform of $sgn(t)$ is :

$\mathcal{F}[sgn(t)] = \frac{1}{πfj}$

Thus

$\frac{1}{πt} ↔ -j* \frac{1}{jπf} =  - \frac{1}{πf}$

Therefore if we apply the duality again on this result we ge

$\frac{1}{πt}  = -j sgn(f)$

Comment: It is hard to understand your steps above. Adding more words about what you are doing in each step would help. Also what do you mean by "multiply by $j=j/j(πt)$"? You should also add the notation you are using, as it is not clear what $U$, $x$ etc. are here.

Comment: @dustin could you add text edit to my post please again since I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The duality property is the statement that if

$$\mathcal{F}(h(t)) = H(\omega)$$

then

$$\mathcal{F}(H(t)) = h(-\omega)$$

To use the duality property to prove the statement you need to show that

$$\mathcal{F}\left(i~\text{sign}(t)\right) = -\frac{1}{\omega\pi}$$

This can be done by a direct computation of $\mathcal{F}\left(i~\text{sign}(t)\right)$. To do this note that

$$\frac{d}{dx} \text{sign} (x) = 2\delta(x)$$

and by using the property

$$ \mathcal{F}\left(\frac{dg(x)}{dx}\right) = 2\pi i\omega \mathcal{F}(g(x))$$

togeather with $\mathcal{F}(\delta) = 1$ the result follows (I have used the convention $\mathcal{F}(g) \equiv \int g(x)e^{-2\pi i \omega} dx$ above).

Comment: Thank you for clarification, I know that the above steps are confusing, I didn't wrote those steps that's why I didn't understand it, getting hint by your solution I came up with the proof using another properties because I didn't really get the rest of your steps. I have edited my post you can check it.